# Element sort with custom rules

Tags: javascript

Rules:

There must be at least three elements side by side.

It can be of different colors from the same number, or can be of the same color from consecutive numbers.

There must be a free space between those that match.

Elements that do not work should be added at the end, respectively.

For example:
Random elements:

```
<ul class="sort">
    <li class="text-primary">6</li>
    <li class="text-danger">6</li>
    <li class="text-primary">9</li>
    <li class="text-danger">1</li>
    <li class="text-success">12</li>
    <li class="text-black">7</li>
    <li class="text-success">10</li>
    <li class="joker">*</li>
    <li class="text-success">9</li>
    <li class="text-danger">7</li>
    <li class="text-primary">11</li>
    <li class="text-black">5</li>
    <li class="text-success">5</li>
    <li class="text-primary">4</li>
    <li class="text-black">4</li>
    <li class="text-danger">12</li>
    <li class="text-black">9</li>
    <li class="text-danger">13</li>
    <li class="text-primary">12</li>
    <li class="text-success">2</li>
    <li class="text-success">6</li>
    <li class="text-success">6</li>
</ul>
```

Need sort like this:

1-2-3 (text-danger*3)

1-1-1 (text-danger , text-primary , text-success)

1-2-3-4 (text-success*4)

Can not:

1-1-1 (text-success*3)

Like a this:

```
<li class="text-success">6</li>
<li class="text-danger">6</li>
<li class="text-primary">6</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-primary">12</li>
<li class="text-danger">12</li>
<li class="text-success">12</li>
<li class="joker">*</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-primary">9</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-primary">11</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-black">9</li>
<li class="text-success">9</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-black">7</li>
<li class="text-danger">7</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-success">5</li>
<li class="text-black">5</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-primary">4</li>
<li class="text-black">4</li>
<li>space</li>
<li class="text-danger">1</li>
<li class="text-success">2</li>
<li class="text-success">6</li>
<li class="text-success">10</li>
<li class="text-danger">13</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written some sort of solution for this problem. First i have created array of object of classname and value of li.

Then i have sorted all array object according to values.

Apply condition check on sorted Array.
(I havent applied space between because i was not clear about that logic).

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

const arrPair = [];
lis.forEach(li => {
  var obj = {
    class: li.className,
    value: parseInt(li.innerText)
  }
  arrPair.push(obj);
});


for(var i = 0;i<arrPair.length;i++)
{
  for(var j = 0;j<arrPair.length;j++)
  {
      if(arrPair[i].value <= arrPair[j].value)
      {
        var temp = arrPair[i];
        arrPair[i] = arrPair[j];
        arrPair[j] = temp;
      }
  }
}
var found = [];
for(var i = 0;i<arrPair.length - 2;i++)
{
  if(arrPair[i].value === arrPair[i+1].value && arrPair[i].value === arrPair[i+2].value && arrPair[i].class !== arrPair[i+1].class && arrPair[i].class !== arrPair[i+2].class && arrPair[i+1].class !== arrPair[i+2].class)
  {
    
    var temp = {
      id1: i,
      id2: i+1,
      id3: i+2,
    }
    found.push(temp);
  }
  if(arrPair[i].value + 1 === arrPair[i+1].value && arrPair[i+1].value + 1 === arrPair[i+2].value && arrPair[i].class === arrPair[i+1].class && arrPair[i].class === arrPair[i+2].class)
  {
  console.log("Here");
    var temp = {
      id1: i,
      id2: i+1,
      id3: i+2
    }
    found.push(temp);
  }
}
$('.sort').empty();
found.forEach(item => {
var li = "";
  li = `<li class='${arrPair[item.id1].class}'>${arrPair[item.id1].value}</li>`;
  li = li + `<li class='${arrPair[item.id2].class}'>${arrPair[item.id2].value}</li>`;
  li = li + `<li class='${arrPair[item.id3].class}'>${arrPair[item.id3].value}</li>`;
  
  $('.sort').append(li);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort">
    <li class="text-primary">6</li>
    <li class="text-danger">6</li>
    <li class="text-primary">9</li>
    <li class="text-danger">1</li>
    <li class="text-success">12</li>
    <li class="text-black">7</li>
    <li class="text-success">10</li>
    <li class="text-success">9</li>
    <li class="text-danger">7</li>
    <li class="text-primary">11</li>
    <li class="text-black">5</li>
    <li class="text-success">5</li>
    <li class="text-primary">4</li>
    <li class="text-black">4</li>
    <li class="text-danger">12</li>
    <li class="text-black">9</li>
    <li class="text-danger">13</li>
    <li class="text-primary">12</li>
    <li class="text-success">2</li>
    <li class="text-success">6</li>
    <li class="text-success">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: (Even if this solution is not as per your requirement, please don't downvote answer, becuase it take lots of effort for writing logic)